# is there a way to show a child element outside the boundaries of a parent with overflow:hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, overflow

I'm working on a plugin that allows popover panels in Jquery Mobile.

A panel will look like this:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-panel="popover" data-id="my_name">
    // JQM pages
</div>
```

and goes after the content section of a JQM page.

Sample (buggy) here: [sample](http://www.stokkers.mobi/jqm/multiview/test/fix_pop.html)

[image: popover sample]

Panels behave like viewports or pageContainers. JQM by default only uses the **body** as pageContainer. My plugin also allows panels, so you integrate popovers into the normal navigation.

**My problem**:
I added triangles to the popovers, but I need to keep panel *CSS overflow-x: hidden* thereby hiding triangles. If I comment out overflow:hidden, the triangle is visible, but when I'm changing pages, the panel "bleeds out", like so:

[image: triangle visible, but panel is bleeding]

As the content section determines the scrollbar, I tried shuffling *overflow:hidden* around, also setting it on the page inside the popover but nothing works. I don't want to move the triangle outside of the panel, so:

**Question:**
Is there a way to show a child element outside of a parent with overflow:hidden or why do does setting overflow-x:hidden hide my triangle, which is on top/bottom (more y than x)?

Just looking for some ideas or other workarounds.

Thanks for help!

**EDIT:**
here is the triangle CSS:

```
.popover_triangle { 
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 0%; 
    width: 0px; border-top: 16px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    border-left: 16px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    border-right: 16px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    border-bottom: 16px solid black;  
    }
.ui-triangle-top .popover_triangle { 
    top: -32px;
    }
.ui-triangle-bottom .popover_triangle { 
    bottom: -34px;
    }
```

The popover has:

```
.ui-popover { 
    position:  absolute; 
    z-index:1005 !important; 
    border: 3px solid black;  
    border-radius: 4px; 
    left: auto; 
    }
.popover1 { 
    margin-top: 3.25em; 
    right: 5em;  
    height:25em; 
    width: 15em; 
    top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Not exactly relevant, but the default scrollbar looks somewhat out of place with the rest of your look and feel.

Comment: @JAB. Because I tried to make a screenshot during transitions... took a while.... Check the sample page, no scrollbars by default

Comment: Can you post the code section and css for where the triangle is put?

Comment: @frequent On the sample page, if I'm looking at the correct bit, the triangles show for me and the content stays within its box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make child visible outside an overflow:hidden parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387489/make-child-visible-outside-an-overflowhidden-parent)

Comment: @AndrewPeacock - mh. My Firefox (latest) doesn't show them

Comment: @frequent Maybe try adding the triangles as a `background-image` to whatever element contains the "Pop D2" and "Pop D3" text?

Comment: Oh. I'm just thinking CSS before/after...

Comment: @frequent I was about to post an answer but it looks like you've already got the idea. If you use the CSS pseudo-class `:before` you can add the triangle as a sibling of the element rather than as a child which won't work due to the `overflow` property on the element.

Comment: Here is a demo of using `:after` to add this type of effect: http://jsfiddle.net/necolas/hjMqh/

Comment: @Jasper: you want to make this an answer, so I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, with overflow-x: hidden, you cannot have that triangle sticking out of the popover with absolute positioning... I have tried this on various browsers!

What you need to do, is create another div *inside* your popover, and apply and overflow-y: scroll or auto to that div. (I assume you might have meant overflow-y instead of overflow-x, since the scrollbar is vertical?) Leave the normal overflow to your popover element. To get overflow-y: auto to that inside div working properly, you need to give it a height, eg height: 100%. (If you can't specify a pixel amount and 100% does not make space for other elements in the popover, there is other ways to work around that)

Eg:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-panel="popover" data-id="my_name">
    // JQM pages
    <!-- insert extra DIV here that contains content and hidden overflow -->
</div>
```

Comment: ok. I gave up on this. your info is correct, so you get the check. Thanks!

Comment: np! I had just been working on a popup with arrow like this recently.