# how to make a ul 's elements go outside a div with overflow set to hidden

Tags: css

I have a div with some content in it which includes a ul with a list of names the div tag has overflow set to hidden  and height :auto so that it increases in height with the content .However i have a ul with a list of names and i want the list to go outside the box . something like the facebook add people autocomplete . The people list shows outside the box

heres my syntax

```
   <div>

    <!-- content goes here -->

    <ul><!-- names go here --> </ul>


    </div>
```

updated

```
<div><!-- div with overflow set to hidden-->

<ul class="selected"></ul><!-- ul containing selected elements-->

<ul class="users"></ul> <!-- list of users -->


</div>

div{overflow:hidden}

.selected{overflow:hidden}

.users{position:absolute}
```

I need the users div to go outside the box but because the parent div is set to overflow hidden it gets cut off. I cannot remove the overflow hidden because as the div with class selected gets more elements the parent div wont expand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You simply cannot.

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/udezuh/2/edit) shows that you cannot 'push-out' from an `overflow:hidden` element an inner children.
The answer would be: **don't use overflow:hidden;** .

Or: you might want to check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387489/make-child-visible-outside-an-overflowhidden-parent) answer

Comment: ok thank you .then my next question would be how would i get  the parent container to expand as elements are added to the ul with class selected

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: relative` to ul.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/57NmY/

Comment: I forgot to add the css my bad . The ul is already positioned relatively

Comment: can you update your question with CSS code if a problem is still around?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, if you position the child element absolutely. -> http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/CX5n9/