# Absolutely positioned block againt any element in the document

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-position

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAm2A/3/

The goal is to position certain popup(`div.absolute-block`) window against(relative to) any dom element on any page with different html structure.
In order to be able to position popup absolutely, we need to  embed  it  into that dom element, having previously wrapped div.absolute-block with relatively or absolutely positioned block (`div.relative1` in our example).
The trouble is that if dom element, we embedded popup in, has block with overfillw: hidden (`div.overflow1`) among it's ancestors, `div.overflow1` will probably crop popup.   `div.overflow1` may be positioned relatively and we cannot influence it in our situation.

The second approach is to append our popup to page body. In this case we face problem of positioning our popup relatively to certain dom element. We can calculate and set top and left properties for popup on document ready event. But in case of window resizing, ajax  content changes or any events changing position of tracked element we have to recalculate popup position.

I think whether there could be some new html 5 features that will let me position popup without embedding it into dom element, i want to position popup relative to? Any other ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to have a child element escape a parent element that has `overflow` set to `hidden`. If you want to have an element positioned exactly over the top of a certain element on the page, your safest option is to put it at the root of the document, use Javascript to calculate and adjust the position, and update on window resize, etc. You might be interested in using jQuery's [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) (relative to parent) or [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) (relative to entire document) methods to help calculate this.

Also, here's a somewhat-related question on the `overflow: hidden` issue which might help:  [Make child visible outside an overflow:hidden parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387489/626682)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but tracking all events that can affect the position and positioning our popup will work bad, will slow down. In addition - there are many such events, and it is difficult to track all of they