# CSS Selectors & Bootstrap Carousel: cannot get overflow visible

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ghost

For some reason I cannot specifically override the overflow hidden property of the `.inner-carousel`.

This code does the job in the general case:

```
   .carousel-inner{
      overflow: visible;
    }
```

But I want it in the specific case that only when I use the `aside` tag inside the carousel divs that the overflow will become visible (i.e. the aside will be visible).

Strangely enough, this code does not work.

```
   .carousel-inner aside {
      overflow: visible;
    }
```

What could be going on?

I recreated a minimal example on [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8iVfiXeAKx).

When you change `.carousel-inner aside{` to `.carousel-inner{` the result that I want will work. The problem is that it then applies to all elements and I only want to apply it to `aside`.

Edit: I've noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387489/make-child-visible-outside-an-overflowhidden-parent) question gives a direct answer to my problem. For some reason though I can't get the solutions implemented. So if someone has another suggestion I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible in CSS as you can't really target "parents" with selectors based on a specific children configuration. You would then need some javascript/jQuery code to run in order to add a class to all divs being direct parent of an aside element.

Here's a jQuery example :

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('aside').each(function(){
        $(this).parents('.carousel-inner').addClass('withaside');
    });
});
```

And the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/su83yo5k/

Once you implement this, you can easilly attach any property to this class, was it `overflow` or in the case of my example the basic text color...