# Overwrite parent's `overflow-hidden` to display drop down content

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have two drop-down and modal components with highly customized styles. When the drop-down is inside the modal, the overflow of the drop-down is hidden due to the style of modal (hidden overflow). And the style of the modal cannot be changed because it needs to be scrollable for larger content.

This is my abstract structure and style:

```html
<div class="ReactModalPortal">
  <div style="position: fixed; inset: 0px;z-index: 3;">
    <div style="position: absolute; overflow-y: hidden" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div style="overflow-y: hidden">
        <div style="overflow-y: auto">
          <div>
            <form>
              <div>
                <div style="position: relative;" >
                    {/* Drop down list */}
                  <ul style="position: absolute; z-index: 9; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto;"></ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When all the parent `overflow` and `overflow-y` are back to default, the problem is solved but the modal is not scrollable anymore.

What can be done with minimum changes in order to display the `ul` out of modal scope?

Comment: @SercanSebetçi Sure. Thanks for the suggestion. I've added. But I feel like it's more of a CSS issue.

Comment: @SercanSebetçi what does React have to do with CSS display issue?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387489/make-child-visible-outside-an-overflowhidden-parent